# Too many parantheses when sending JSON from iOS to Rails (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying use the following to encode some data:

```
NSDictionary *mydata = @{@"user": @{@"uuid" : tfUUID.text,
                                    @"username" : tfUserName.text,
                                    @"email" : tfEmailAddress.text,
                                    @"password" : tfPassword.text,
                                    @"password_confirmation" : tfPasswordConfirm.text}
                        };

NSData *sentData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mydata options:0 error:nil];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:sentData completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

NSDictionary *returnedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

NSLog(@"Error is: %@", error);

NSDictionary *returnedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

NSLog(@"The data I have received back is: %@", returnedData);

}];
```

I'm then sending it to a Rails backend using a POST/PUT request.

When sent, the rails server is reporting that it can't find a param called "user".

The output I'm seeing is:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-18 12:16:20 +1100
Processing by UsersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"{\"user\":{\"password\":\"********\",\"uuid\":\"********\",\"username\":\"********\",\"email\":\"********\",\"password_confirmation\":\"********\"}}"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: user):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:106:in `user_params'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:42:in `create'
```

Rather too many parentheses and backslashes perhaps?

According to rails (when I use the web front end to achieve the same, it's "expecting":

```
Parameters: {"user"=>{"uuid"=>"*******", "username"=>"*******", "email"=>"*******", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Register"}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong in the JSON encoding in objective-c?

This confusing me and would appreciate any advice!

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: Does any of parameters contain any special characters maybe ?

Comment: No. They are all sent as text. No special characters allowed. But thanks for asking. This is driving me mad!

Comment: Can you print / write to file decode information from rails ? Becuase probably what you pasted it's from xcode - it contains some crap inside which is not there only when you po to console

Comment: Solved ... which I'm sort of getting used to! See answer for anyone else who has problems ...

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer, not as part of your question.  Also, this looks like it may be a bug in the `NSURLSession` library.

Comment: I did try and answer it, but needed to wait 8 hours before answering my own question (Website rules). But felt I needed to post the response before anyone else tried to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem lay with setting up a NSURLSession.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30.0;
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60.0;
sessionConfig.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
  NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig
                                  delegate:self
                             delegateQueue:nil];
```

I had two additional lines as part of the sessionConfig code:

```
[sessionConfig setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{@"Accept": @"application/json"}];
[sessionConfig setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{@"Content-Type": @"application/json"}];
```

Which, when I deleted them, and placed them in the NSURLMutableRequest instead:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:homeURL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

It worked first time.

Have to admit to having NO idea why this didn't work ... and if anyone can enlighten me, I would be grateful.

But I can now move on to the next problem.